# Capture original ASP.net Error page and send as email and display User Friendly message/page

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

I would like to be able to send an email with the same html that get generated when an exception occurs in asp.net however not to display this to the user.

Would this be simple? or would it just be best to manually output the exception details to an email?

Answer (score 2):

You should look into a popular library called elmah:

- http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

It will log your errors and let you view the original YSOD (yellow screen of death) and you can also optionally have them emailed to you.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention this but I actually only got around to trying elmah finally when nupack was released. I got caught up in all the hype of installing elmah in seconds and had a bit of a false start with it. 1 - remote viewing wasn't prohibited which was a security risk. 2 - by default it only logs to memory (ram) so when an error occurred it kept wiping the logs out. Having said that I think there are some updated articles out there now that explain how to use nuget + config it correctly.